# Good example fo xsl transition in excel

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have simple XML, but I want to open XML in excel. Anyone knows good example for xlst transtition ?

Comment: Just searching my own answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824098/xml-to-xls-using-java and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple XML, you shouldn't need to do anything - Excel can open many simple XML files natively. If it can't understand your XML, your best bet is just to transform it into more tabular XML (i.e. one element per row, then one child per column) and open that instead.